# radio buttons with cookie

Tags: php, forms, cookies, radio-button

I try to set a cookie for 2 radio buttons and i don't know what i do wrong. I need to make it when a button is checked to remain checked even the page is refreshed. Can someone give me an advice with this? Thanks

This is my test.php

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['radio1'])) {
      setcookie('radio1', true, 600, '/');
      setcookie('radio2', false, 600, '/');
    } else if(isset($_POST['radio2'])) {
      setcookie('radio2', true, 600, '/');
      setcookie('radio1', false, 600, '/');
    }
    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="test.php">
      <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" checked="checked" />
        <label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" />
        <label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite follow your code, but the following should check the correct radio button for you:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio']=='val1') {
  setcookie('radio1', true, 600, '/');
  $radio1=' checked ';
  $radio2='';
  setcookie('radio2', false, 600, '/');
} else if(isset($_POST['radio'])&& $_POST['radio']=='val2') {
  setcookie('radio2', true, 600, '/');
  $radio1='';
  $radio2=' checked ';
  setcookie('radio1', false, 600, '/');
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="test.php">
  <div id="radio">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" <?php echo $radio1;?> value="val1" />
<label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" <?php echo $radio2;?> value="val2" />
<label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
<input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is still not working. I check a button i give refresh and nothing happens, both of them are unchecked. Do i have do add something else to this code like a submit button or javascript?

Comment: @Cola Looking at the code in more detail, I see that we missed setting a value and checking for it in the PHP code. The ID associated with the tag means something to CSS and Javascript, but nothing to PHP. With radio buttons, we need to check the value. I updated the code.

Comment: i checked and is not working. There is another way to do this without cookies?

Comment: @Cola The above code (Removed anything but the working code) works for me as it is (I added a submit button) and it saves the data from form submission to form submission. Have you changed your form to match the answer - adding in the `value='val1'` bits?

Comment: from a page to another i mean with $GET or something like this because how do i really need this radio is when someone check a button and press search from my homepage when he gets to the next page to remain the option that he chose. but on the homepage page the default checked to be radio1 always. I think is more simple.

Answer (score 1):

This is `checked="checked"` for W3C not just `checked`

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] == "radio1") {
        setcookie('radio1', "true", 600, '/');
        setcookie('radio2', "false", 600, '/');
        $radio1 = ' checked="checked"';
        $radio2 = '';
    } else if(isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] == "radio2") {
        setcookie('radio1', "false", 600, '/');
        setcookie('radio2', "true", 600, '/');
        $radio1 = '';
        $radio2 = ' checked="checked"';
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE['radio1']) && $_COOKIE['radio1'] == "true") {
        $radio1 = ' checked="checked"';
        $radio2 = '';
    } else if (isset($_COOKIE['radio2']) && $_COOKIE['radio2'] == "true") {
        $radio1 = '';
        $radio2 = ' checked="checked"';
    }
    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="test.php">
        <div id="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="radio1" <?= $radio1; ?> />
            <label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="radio2" <?= $radio2; ?> />
            <label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I forgot to test the cookies value, try now. :)

Comment: do i have to add javascript or a submit button ?

Comment: No, my bad, I didn't test your code, you forgot the value in your radios.